# What do graphene "armchair(5,5)" and "zigzag(5,0)" refer to?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, nomenclature, carbon-allotropes

I am reading some articles about the electronic properties of graphene and while reading it I came across graphene armchair and zigzag structures, which have different bond structures.

The two different orientations (armchair and zigzag) are due to the arrangement of carbon atoms in the periphery ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene)), but I am unable to understand what armchair(5,5) and zigzag(5,0) mean.

Comment: For those who are still looking for an answer i found this website [found this website](http://www.understandingnano.com/electrical-properties-carbon-nanotubes.html)  which provides a visual represantation of armchair and zigzag struture

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The third picture, subpic (d) [here](http://www.ifw-dresden.de/institutes/iff/research/Carbon/molecular-nanostructures/graphene) shows you the geometric armchair(red) and zigzag(blue) structure:

[image]

It's derived from  structure description of [Carbon nanotubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_nanotube#Single-walled) similar to [surface reconstruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_reconstruction)/[overlayer structures](http://www.chem.qmul.ac.uk/surfaces/scc/scat6_1.htm):

> The integers n and m denote the number of unit vectors along two directions in the honeycomb crystal lattice of graphene. If m = 0, the nanotubes are called zigzag nanotubes, and if n = m, the nanotubes are called armchair nanotubes. Otherwise, they are called chiral. The diameter of an ideal nanotube can be calculated from its (n,m) indices

I hope you have some background, otherwise here is a [nice visualisation](https://vimeo.com/1086112), or look the lecture linked above. It's important to understand what the unit cell of a 3D crystal or 2D surface is.